# Example of non accessible model categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories, accessible-categories, locally-presentable-categories

By curiosity, I would like to see an example of a model category with the underlying category locally presentable which is not accessible [in this sense](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/accessible+model+category) (and just in case: even by using Vopěnka's principle).

Comment: I am very confused by the question, if the underlying category is locally presentable, then it is accessible in first place.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Accessible as a model category, with accessible weak factorization systems.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I put a link towards the nLab for the definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know whether set-theoretic hypotheses are necessary to answer this question.  But if we assume the negation of Vopěnka's principle, here is an example: by Example 6.12 of Adamek-Rosicky *Locally presentable and accessible categories* the locally presentable category $\bf Gra$ of graphs has a reflective subcategory that is not accessible, and by Proposition 3.5 of [Salch](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00508) *The Bousfield localizations and colocalizations of the discrete model structure* this reflector is the fibrant replacement functor of a model structure on $\bf Gra$.

Answer (score 7):

An example which does not depend on set theory is the [equivariant model structure](https://doi.org/10.1090/s0002-9939-1987-0897092-6) on the category of maps of spaces by Emmanuel Farjoun.

Comment: Are you sure it is not accessible ? it is not combinatorial of couse. but I think it is accessible. Well to be honest I don't quite know about the version using actual space but then the underlying category is not locally presentable. I claim that a similar construction using simplicial sets instead would be accessible however.

Comment: I was trying to write a rigorous proof recently, but did not succeed so far. I  still believe  that the main idea is correct and hope to finish the argument eventually. Frankly, I would be happier if the equivariant model structure turns out to be accessible, so if you have a proof (for simplicial sets, of course), please tell me.